# Overlay Text applied on pdf through is not printed through java printing

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

I am working on a requirement to apply overlay with text on a pdf using iText 7.0.4. Ovlery gets applied on source pdf without any issues and I can print through the Acrobat File -> Print and the pdf gets printed with the overlay information fine. When I try to print the pdf using PDFBox2.0.3/Java code the overlay text is not printed but the rest of the text on the pdf gets printed fine.

By looking at the pdf there is a font included like Arial MT (Embedded), Type:TrueType,Encoding: Ansi. I used Arail as the Font for the overlayed text.
I see the below errors in the log while printing through java code

13:27:49.813 [Finalizer] DEBUG o.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer - ScratchFileBuffer not closed!

13:28:28.726 [main] DEBUG o.apache.fontbox.ttf.PostScriptTable - No PostScript name information is provided for the font ArialMT

The same code prints the pdf including the overlay text  when I save the pdf as a new pdf document using PDF Optimizer. 
I see an additional font ArialMT (Embedded Subset) added in the properties -> Fonts of the pdf in addition to the ArialMT font.

I found this link to be useful while debugging https://support.visiolink.com/hc/en-us/articles/200003811-How-to-fix-Disappearing-or-Strange-Looking-Elements-in-the-PDF

Any pointers on why text is missing during the java print would be helpful.

Below is the pdf link and code used to print the pdf.

### Issue is that the L203040OT in the pdf does not get printed with the java code.

The code works with PDFBox 1.8.15 but not with 2.0.10.

Executing the 'Printingpdf.java' code With PDFBox 1.8.15 version I see log trace as 
"11:59:08.213 [main] INFO  o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font - Using font SansSerif.plain instead of Arial". 
The same code executed with 2.0.10 version has the log trace as 
"22:50:04.226 [main] DEBUG o.apache.fontbox.ttf.PostScriptTable - No PostScript name information is provided for the font Calibri".

Pdf link https://github.com/ashokvytla/myproject/blob/master/659192_print.pdf

### java Code:

```
package printing;

import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PageRanges;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageable;
public class Printingpdf {

public static PDDocument _pdfDocument=null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String printername="defaultprinter";
        String templateFillablePDFFile = "printingdocs/659192_print.pdf";
        PrinterJob printerjob=PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printerjob.setPrintService(PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService());
        _pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File (templateFillablePDFFile));
        //printerjob.setPageable(new PDFPageable(_pdfDocument));  //uncomment this 2.0.10
        printerjob.setPageable(new PDPageable(_pdfDocument));   //Comment this for 2.0.10
        PrintRequestAttributeSet  attributes=new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        int pageRangesArr[][]={ {1,2}   };
        attributes.add(new PageRanges(pageRangesArr));
          if(printerjob.printDialog()) {
            printerjob.print(attributes);
        }

        System.out.println("printer name==>"+printername);
        _pdfDocument.close();
     } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but if you only need to do simple printing then have you considered using `Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File("Your PDF"));` instead of PDFBox? The only requirement is that the OS has an associated PDF application installed, and any PDF application should be able to print your missing text.

Comment: Please retry with the latest version and share your PDF.

Comment: Indeed, without you sharing the PDF we can hardly help you. And depending on what turns out to be the issue with PDFBox rendering the PDF, it may well be necessary to also share the code creating the overlay.

Comment: Hi Ashok, I see that you are already in touch with Lebo at iText Software. She has forwarded your question to our developers, who will get back to you as soon as possible. Please keep in mind that questions on Stack Overflow are answered on a voluntary basis, without any guarantee of correctness and timeliness.

Comment: I could display the file with 1.8 and 2.0.11 and also print. Make sure that you don't mix several versions, i.e. that there are only 2.0.11 versions in your classpath. Don't use old versions.